# Butterknife not working with the adapter class

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, butterknife

I have created a base `recyclerview` and my other class is extending the baseclass. I have implemented the [butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/).However when the other class is extending the base class I am getting the view as null.

Below is my base class

```
public abstract class BaseAdapter<T>
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<T> mObjects;
    private Context context;

    public BaseAdapter(final List<T> objects, Context context) {
        this.mObjects = objects;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(getActivityLayout(), parent, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,parent);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    /**
     * Adds the specified object at the end of the array.
     *
     * @param object The object to add at the end of the array.
     */
    public void add(final T object) {
        mObjects.add(object);
        notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);
    }

    /**
     * Remove all elements from the list.
     */
    public void clear() {
        final int size = getItemCount();
        mObjects.clear();
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mObjects.size();
    }

    public T getItem(final int position) {
        return mObjects.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the position of the specified item in the array.
     *
     * @param item The item to retrieve the position of.
     * @return The position of the specified item.
     */
    public int getPosition(final T item) {
        return mObjects.indexOf(item);
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the specified object at the specified index in the array.
     *
     * @param object The object to insert into the array.
     * @param index  The index at which the object must be inserted.
     */
    public void insert(final T object, int index) {
        mObjects.add(index, object);
        notifyItemInserted(index);

    }

    /**
     * Removes the specified object from the array.
     *
     * @param object The object to remove.
     */
    public void remove(T object) {
        final int position = getPosition(object);
        mObjects.remove(object);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the content of this adapter using the specified comparator.
     *
     * @param comparator The comparator used to sort the objects contained in this adapter.
     */
    public void sort(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        Collections.sort(mObjects, comparator);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, getItemCount());
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
        }
    }
    protected abstract int getActivityLayout();
}
```

Below is my Subclass

```
    public class SubRecyclerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private List<LocationList> getLocationLists;
        @Nullable
        @BindView(R.id.branchimage)
        ImageView branchimage;
        public SubRecyclerAdapter(List<LocationList> getLocationLists,Context context) {
            super(getLocationLists,context);
            this.context=context;
            this.getLocationLists=getLocationLists;
        }

        @Override
        protected int getActivityLayout() {
            return R.layout.locationlist;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Picasso.with(context) .load(getLocationLists.get(position).getBranch_image()) .placeholder(R.drawable.dummy_image)
                    .error(R.drawable.dummy_image) .into(branchimage);
//branchimage is null here
        }
```

Butterknife version :--

```
 compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
 apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use ButterKnife in your adapter you need to do this way in your view holder and onCreateViewHolder:

```
  //View Holder for performance optimizations of the recycler view display
    static class AddProductsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        @InjectView(R.id.product_image)
        ImageView productImage;
        @InjectView(R.id.product_name)
        TextView productName;
        @InjectView(R.id.product_brand)
        TextView productBrand;

        public final View mView;

        public AddProductsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            ButterKnife.inject(this, itemView);
        }
    }

 @Override
    public AddProductsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View productView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row_products, parent, false);
        return new AddProductsViewHolder(productView);
    }
```

Usage:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AddProductsViewHolder holder, int position) {

        try{
            AddProductInfo addProductInfo = addProductInfoList.get(position);

            if(!addProductInfo.getProductImage().isEmpty()){
            holder.productName.setText(addProductInfo.getProductName());
            holder.productBrand.setText(addProductInfo.getProductBrand());


        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
```

Comment Below if you have any doubts.

With latest version of butterknife you just need To replace `@InjectView` with `@Bind`
This is my old code , but i think it serves your purpose.

Comment: I want to inject ButterKnife in my BaseAdapterClass.Is there any way to do it.Thanks for your comment

Comment: Why cant you add this in your view holder :  ButterKnife.bind(this,parent); as said in answer and if you want to use them in the concrete class just create your own  abstract method and inside the   onBindViewHolder() and inside the onBindViewHolder do the boiler plate operation you want to do and call the abstract method so that the concrete class who ever is implementing the method will take care of its own operations.

Comment: Have you checked my code.I was trying to do it as you said in comment.Can you modify my code and correct my mistake please.

Comment: Why do you need a baseAdapter and an custom implementation of it , you can directly do that in your SubRecyclerAdapter() itself? , Is the adapter (with same layout and functionality) being used in so many places ?

Comment: I know but there are many implementation I want to do in base adapter class.So it will be better if you can help me in that way.